# How to disable indentation on multiline html string

Tags: webstorm

How could I get rid of the WebStorm (re-format) indentation?

// Expected

```
template: $template(
    '<div>' +
        '<label> {{currentLength}} </label>  ' +
    '</div>'
)
```

// Not expected, after applying WebStorm auto format(indentation)

```
template: $template(
    '<div>' +
    '<label> {{currentLength}} </label>  ' +
    '</div>')
```

Comment: Your title and body say you want to get rid of indentation, yet your desired output has extra indentation. Voting to close as Unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will be possible to implement in the form you're suggesting – indenting the parent language expressions (JavaScript) in order to adhere to indenting rules for child (HTML) language. As a workaround, you can turn your multiline string into a template string (with backticks) and add `//language=HTML` comment to get HTML injected and auto-formatted:

```
//language=HTML
template: $template(
        `<div>
            <label> {{currentLength}} </label>
        </div>`)
```